# Why was this question about Microsoft-recommend Roslyn code analyzers in Visual Studio closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234816/what-are-the-microsoft-recommended-roslyn-analyzers-that-visual-studio-prompts) the other day and now noticed it has been closed as off-topic. To me it fits right here:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Visual Studio obviously fits the first bullet point. Roslyn Analyzers do as well. And I do think that it is perfectly answerable.

---

Here is the full text of the question:

> ### What are the "Microsoft-recommended Roslyn analyzers" that Visual Studio prompts me to install?
>
> In Visual Studio 2019, I was almost immediately given a popup by Microsoft saying that it was recommended for me to use Roslyn code analyzers, which supposedly provide additional diagnostics and fixes for some issues.
>
> From a quick Google search, it looks like Roslyn code analyzers are probably already being used in my project, as they appear to come in from a variety of NuGet packages and from other sources.
>
> I did see as well (I believe in a HackerNews article) that Roslyn was Microsoft's C# compiler for C#, which was at some point released, I'm unsure if its the default compiler or not. Separately, I'm really not sure what a code analyzer is, but I imagine it's what it sounds like.
>
> To clarify my question, I suppose it would have to be two parts:
>
> 1. What are code analyzers?
> 2. What are Microsoft's recommended code analyzers, and why aren't they just enabled by default?
>
> [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [visual-studio-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2019) [roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roslyn) [roslyn-code-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roslyn-code-analysis)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan No, but you can get *text*... See update.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the question is valid and falls clearly within Stack Overflow's scope. Although it was originally closed as a request for an external resource, that is clearly not what the question was really about, and certainly not with the clarifying edits that were made subsequent to its closure.

As such, I've re-opened the question.

Comment: But it is "too broad"... And the OP here is the person who answered, so not a selfless request.

Comment: It doesn't strike me as being too broad, @Cindy. A reasonably-scoped answer seems to be possible. I did not miss that the person who asked was the same person who answered, but I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: It's too broad. OP didn't research anything, he just post the question "what is A" and another opinion-based question (or he really think microsoft decision maker will come and answer him?). Nor OP has any *real* problem with it. It's just another "I saw this and I am asking question" question.

Comment: @Sinatr Lack of research doesn’t make a question too broad. A question post is too broad if it has too many questions, there are too many possible answers, or any good answer would be too long.

Comment: Nice job, brave mod.

Comment: @CindyMeister So what? I felt that it wasn't in violation of the site rules. The fact that I answered it or not makes no difference whatsoever. Either it's in violation or it's not. Also, having someone else's question closed makes no difference for me as an answerer, including reputation. It only made a difference for me in the sense that I wanted to help improve SO. And I don't think it's too broad. I answered because as soon as I saw it I remembered how my coworkers had asked that question themselves for a long time. The question, however, have since been deleted... Ludicrous.